# Snippets (snippetsync) only parse when logged in

Tags: snippets, snippet-sync

It seems that some newly created snippets using SnippetSync (version controlled and uploaded via GIT/Beanstalk) begin parse only after I log into the control panel. After a day or so these snippets will appear as {snippet:snippetgroup_snippetname} once again and logging into the CP will get the snippets to parse once again.

This does not affect all snippets, but only recently created ones. Perhaps post upgrade to 2.5.5? Not confirmed.

Using EE 2.5.5.

Am I missing a setting? Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I've never seen that behavior. Have you tried to disable and re-enable the extension? When a site is in heavy development it can sometimes get the timestamps crossed, especially when multiple developers are involved. Uninstall and re-install re-syncs the files and fixes the timestamps. No snippets will be lost.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I just disabled the extension and re-enabled. I will give it a day or so and see if that did the trick. Appreciated.